# Number of Jedi after Order 66?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, order-66

How many Jedi survived Order 66? Was Master Yoda the only one or are there any more who disappeared into the shadows?

Comment: Well... I think Obi Wan counts...

Comment: Do baby luke and leia count? :D

Comment: He [was] no Jedi yet…

Comment: Based on the books and games I'm of the opinion that around 33% of the people in the Star Wars universe are jedi. http://atwitsendcomics.com/comics/index/116/Star-Wars-Kinect

Comment: 66.  When Palpatine realized that, he gave silent thanks that he hadn't called it "Order 983" like he'd originally planned.

Comment: @TGnat Does he become Obi-Too?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the [Star Wars wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Order_66), there were fewer than 100 surviving Jedi after the order, but it was only the start of the [Great Jedi Purge](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Jedi_Purge). For roughly 19 years after, the order continued, but it was ended when there were very few remaining Jedi left.

Comment: That would be a high number seeing as the book " NJO Jedi eclipse" said that they (the NJO) had about 150 knights and that was nearly the number as "the apex of the old republic".   I know that number came from the wiki but. it may not be that accrete. I would think the number would need to be lower for it to be as bad as say the battle over Mustafa in "Attack of the Clones"

Comment: @Vaughn: That might be the case, but maybe the 150 number was the number of full jedi, and the 100 included some apprentices? Will have to think on that one for a while...

Comment: Update/Edit of first comment - After thinking more it was in one of the "Dark nest" (Unseen Queen, I think) series, when Luke is made "Grand Master of the Jedi". That one was loaned to me by a friend, so I can not confirm that number (150) the way I would like.

Comment: @Vaughn - I'm fairly sure there were far more than 150 Jedi in the old republic. There were thousands that perished during the Clone Wars, and even if the reference was to "The Old Republic" (thousands of years BBY), there were still many more. (100+ Jedi perished during the 7th Battle of Ruusan, and there were plenty left)

Comment: @SSumner here's a quote from the movie to back you up. Yoda about the battle of Geonosis: "Throughout the galaxy, thousands of Jedi there are. To send on a special mission, only two hundred are available."

Answer (score 12):

The Force Unleashed is not strict canon, but it does indicate that a number of Jedi survived the order, as your character is required to hunt down a number of Jedi hiding in various locations.

Answer (score 10):

Various semi-canonical sources (novels, etc) indicate that

1. some Jedi survived the purges
2. Not all force users were Jedi nor Sith
3. Not all Jedi were targeted

We see Mara Jade and at least one other dark apprentice in the novels, plus at least two non-Jedi, non-Sith force users in the Heir to the Empire trilogy.

It's probably safe to say that Obi Wan and Yoda are the last of the Council's Jedi Masters; various failed apprentices and former Jedi seem to be out there as well, EG Count Duku. (Dark Empires, Eps II & III) Rebels shows us a couple other Jedi Knights also survived.

Plus, there are implications that there were other Jedi temples with training centers, and that not all might have been found.

Answer (score 1):

I know that Ferus Olin survived and goes through a story in the Last of the Jedi series by Scholastic, where he rescues two other Jedi and starts a Jedi rescue base on an asteroid.

Answer (score 0):

Some clones didn't follow Order 66 and those Jedi escaped, as did the ones who were almost killed like Yoda or Kenobi.

Comment: This actually is Legends cannon, in the Republic Commandos books.