# Did Jedi have ranks?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

Inspired by [apoorv020's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6513/why-are-all-jedi-given-a-rank-of-general-in-the-clone-wars) -

Did Jedi have any official/semiofficial rankings beyond padavan/Knight/Master/Council member?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not really, if you add in Initiates and Grand Master ranks

Take a look [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_ranks#Jedi_ranks) for details, but, in a list format:

Base options:

- Jedi Initiate (or Youngling or "Jedi Hopeful")
- Jedi Padawan
- Jedi Knight
- Jedi Master
- Jedi Grand Master (Only 1 at a time; head of the order.)

After Knighthood, they could specialize further but the specialties did not affect the ranking.

Comment: But aren't these all just specialties and they are still just same-ranked Knights or Masters?

Comment: Well, they still only went up to Master, but there were specialty masters; Warrior Master, Sage Master and so forth.. Although still masters, they had all the qualities of a generic master PLUS their specialty; hence the title.  But master was as high as they went, except for the Wartime titles, and, of course the head of the order, the Grand Master.  It's comparable (no surprise) to how many monastic orders are setup; unless you are a god/avatar/etc, Master/Grand Master is as high as you go.

Comment: while it's a good answer, all of it (except for the first paragraph) doesn't really address my question which was specifically about **ranks**, not titles. I'll edit out the off-topic details if you don't mind.

Comment: Well,  I think of them as ranks, the way a some of the specialty ranks are ranks.. I.e., a Warrior Master v.s. Master -> Technical Sergeant v.s. Staff Sergeant v.s. Sergeant.  But it's not defined that well in "The Jedi Path: A Manual for Students of the Force", so it's your call how to interpret it.

Comment: I define rank as in "who outranks whom in a sense of being authorized to take command". Mind you, Jedi aren't a military outfit but the concepts still holds.

Comment: Ah; that makes sense.. Heh.. If you really want to have fun, we can argue if a Warrior Master is a line officer, where a Sage master isn't.. But I think we've beaten this one into the ground enough... :)

Comment: According to the Jedi Knight video computer games.. there is also a Jedi Lord, which is higher and more powerful than even Jedi Master. Kyle Katarn from the games acheived this level, though I don't recall it ever being in any of the books, not even in the EU books, though Luke would certainly have attained that level for sure in terms of raw power, force skills and abiltiies, lightsaber combat and skills, etc.

Comment: The "pecking order" within the Jedi doesn't work like the military. The titles listed in this answer are the closest thing they have to ranks. Who "out-ranks" who is determined by a combination of Title, role, and influence. Short of being the Grand Master yourself, the best you could hope for is a Jedi Master, have a seat on the Council, and be the head of your specialty division.