# Is there rank within the Jedi Council?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

I don't remember this being clarified: Is there someone overall in charge of the Jedi Council or is their way entirely democratic? Are they all equal, or are senior members more influential and privileged?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYVIs-Z1LM8

Comment: Possible dupe of [Did Jedi Have Ranks](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6526/did-jedi-have-ranks?rq=1)?

Comment: I don't feel that the answer to that question answers mine, though it is interesting. I want to know if, to put it simply, your video had a good grasp of the situation.

Comment: Yeah- master, grand master ,knight, apprentice, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Wookieepedia (the Star Wars wiki) there are two designated titles outside of general council member: **Grand Master** and **Master of the Order**. While both of the titles can be occupied by the same person (including, but not limited to, Yoda) they are two *separate* ranks of the Jedi Order.

> Grand Master was a title used in both the Old and New Jedi Orders to
>   describe the recognized head of the Order. While separate from the
>   title Master of the Order, which was used to describe the elected
>   leader of the Jedi High Council, the positions were often filled by
>   the same person

(from the [Grand Master](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Grand_Master) wiki).

> Master of the Order was a title used to denote the elected leader of
>   the Jedi High Council during the last decades of the Old Republic, and
>   was also used by the New Jedi Order. Even though the title was
>   separate from the title of Grand Master, the positions were oftentimes
>   granted to the same individual

(from the [Master of the Order](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Master_of_the_Order) wiki).

Comment: So, essentially, the council are all equal apart from (at the time of the prequels) Yoda, who is recognised as leader of all Jedi? Makes me think of a new question really - is the council just there to advise Yoda?

Comment: To answer your question ThruGog, (this is coming from my select knowledge of the Jedi Council and what I have read from the links that are provided) that yes they all appear to be recognized as council members with equal power. The exception being the Master of the Order and Grand Master. I have also found some information that may help clarify some things: "The High Council was a group of twelve wise and powerful Jedi Masters who were elected to guide the Order as well as to serve as an advisory body for the Office of the Supreme Chancellor [Finis Valorum from the Prequel Trilogy]".

Comment: @ThruGog While Yoda was the Grand Master, he was not the Master of the Order at the time of the prequel trilogy.  While he may have held the position at one point in time, Mace Windu was Master of the Order at the time of his death.  So he was technically head of the order (although everyone obviously deferred to Yoda since was Yoda)

Comment: @psubsee2003 They're confusing titles - in the quotes in Todd's answer, it says Master of the Order (Windu) was head of the council, and Grand Master (Yoda) was head of the order.

Comment: @ThruGog there is no mention of Windu in the answer, hence my comment.  I wanted to make sure that the hierarchy you were trying to understand included Mace Windu since he was equally important as Yoda, although "head of the order" was probably the wrong choice of words, but rather "leader of the order."

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. My remarks were directed towards the end of the Jedi Order as seen in the prequel trilogy and in the now non-canon EU. After the death of Windu, Yoda became the sole leader of the Jedi Council, becoming both Grand Master and Master of the Order. He is known to be the last holder of both of these titles (according to Wooliepedia).

Comment: @Todd O'Rourke Your information makes perfect sense, but psubsee2003 your thoughts seem to say that Yoda was head of the council and Windu was head of the order, while the Wookiepedia quotes definitely seem to be the other way around. (You said Windu was either head or leader of the order, when that must be the Grand Master, which was Yoda, according to the quotes).