# Were the Jedi allowed to involve themselves with politics?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

Obviously the Jedi did involve themselves with politics when they became generals of the Clone Wars, since they believed the Republic at the time was a force of good. We all know how that worked out for them.

However, I have a vague memory of them being somehow prohibited from being explicitly involved in politics, ie as a senator or a ruler, but I cannot find anything that definitively says this.

Are Jedi generally forbidden from involving themselves in politics, aside from military positions?

Comment: Related: [How do the Jedi fit in the political structure of the Old Republic?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100736/31394) (Welcome to SFF, by the way!)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thank you! I've been lurking for ages but never had anything to say :)

Comment: Master Kenobi, at least, felt quite negative about politicians. He told Anakin (about Padme): "She's a politician, and they're not to be trusted."

Answer (score 2):

### Legends: Jedi were politicians, for at least a while

*The New Essential Chronology* established that between 2000-1000 years before the Battle of Yavin, Jedi were directly involved in politics:

> These centuries of strife, known as the Draggulch period (2000—1000 B.B.Y.), saw a consistent decline in Republic power as mineral mines ran dry and thousands of mega-corporations went bankrupt. The Republic borders began to shrink for the first time in millennia, as colony worlds dried up and were abandoned. **Hardship bred lawlessness, and the overextended Jedi took a more active role in government. In a move of desperation, several Jedi even served as Republic Supreme Chancellor.** Scandal continued to plague the Jedi, most notably following the military strike against the Ubese that left the Ubese homeworld inhospitable and forced its survivors to live the rest of their lives beneath filtration helmets.
>
> (source: *The New Essential Chronology*, page 26, emphasis added)

Later, *Darth Bane: Rule of Two* elaborated on this by establishing that *all* of the Chancellors from 1400-1000 BBY were Jedi, ending with the election of Tarsus Valorum.

While it doesn't seem that the Jedi returned to this level of involvement between then and the time of the movies, I haven't found anything stating that this was the result of a ban or internal rule within the Order.