# What was the fate of the disbanded former Jedi order members after Order 66 executed?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, order-66

The facts are that:

From the prequel trilogy, we know that when a Jedi gets emotionally close to another person then he/she is dismissed from the Jedi Order. Anakin was afraid this would happen if anyone found out about him and Padme.

As far as I can remember (though I seemed unable to locate my source again) there has been occasions that people (male and female) have been ejected from the Jedi Order because they became too emotionally close with other people and they wanted have a normal life, or even get married. These people though, even though they were removed from the Jedi Order, they didn't lose the powers or skills obtained over years of training.

And the question is:

Why didn't these former Jedi Order show up and help in the fight against the Empire after the Order 66 was executed? Why didn't Yoda or Obi Wan try to contact them after they were rescued by senator Organa? Do we know (from canon or Legends) what their fate was after the Jedi massacre?

[Number of Jedi after Order 66?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/number-of-jedi-after-order-66?rq=1) is asking about Jedi who were still part of the Jedi Order at the time Order 66 was activated. I am asking about the former Jedi that were no longer part of the Order.

Comment: I suspect Vader would hunt them down. Can't allow any Force users to stick around that could take out the Emperor.

Comment: @RichS could be true, Vader also has access to the Jedi Archives, so he could find them from that...... so thats one possibility :)

Comment: Vader was meant to bring balance to the force... Balance would imply TWO jedi (joda & Kenobi) or all force welders dead

Comment: @Naib wow now you open a very very long discussion.... the "balance" that you  refer to, can be translated in many many ways... for us balance means that two things are equal numbered, for the jedi's bringing balance means to kill all siths and only jedi's to exist... so as you see everyone makes his own translation of the "balance". And just for you to know, because of the jedi translation of "balance", Anakin, aka Vader actually brought balance to the force (so he fullfilled the prophecy) because eventually he killed the dark sith lord... (it took him some time, but in the end he did)

Comment: very true he eventually brought "balance" by killing the sith, but that not balance ;) yin and yang. a thousand Jedi on the "light" and two sith on the "dark" is not balanced. One Jedi and two sith is not balanced, one jedi is not balanced.  :)

Comment: @Naib for us this is true, but dont get confused, that is a different universe, so different laws, different interpretentions..... bringing balance for the Jedi meant to kill all the sith..... so he did....

Comment: In *Star Wars: A New Dawn*, it's explained that Kanaan stayed in hiding because A) Obi-Wan told everyone to in his emergency message and B) a bit of survivor's guilt. But he was a kid when he went into hiding.

Comment: @Naib I believe the theory is that the Light Side is in tune with nature, life, the Force, etc. Therefore it is in balance. The Dark Side, however, bends nature, life, the Force, etc. to its will, violently if necessary. Therefore, The Dark Side *IS* the imbalance. It is an aberration, a perversion of The Force and so destroying the Dark Side restores balance to The Force.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in Canon, there is only one Light-sider we know so far who left the Jedi Order, [Ahsoka Tano](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ahsoka_Tano). She left on her own accord, though.

> Because I am no longer a Jedi. It was my choice, I left the Order. (*Shroud of Darkness*)
>
> I am no Jedi. (*Twilight of the Apprentice*)

We don't yet know what she was doing when Order 66 was first enacted, however we do know some of what happened after that.

Firstly, in *Star Wars: Rebels*, Yoda did contact her, to some extent, in the episode *[Shroud of Darkness](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shroud_of_Darkness)*. Kenobi was busy looking after Luke at the time, so he wouldn't have sought her out.

We don't know her final fate, but we do know that the Empire and its Inquisitors are Chaos-bent on capturing or killing her.

[image]

The same is likely true for all non-Empired alligned Force-users, ex-Jedi or otherwise, as we see the Inquisitors kidnapping force-sensitive babies for unknown purposes.

Comment: but i do remember that i heard/read somewhere, that there was another case like anakin and padme, only difference that both the male and female were jedi's, and they were both expelled by the Jedi Order for being together....

Comment: @rogue Vader though when contacting palpatine about her called her a jedi so even though SHE doesn't see herself as a jedi any longer....the sith do so....so its just again a matter of point of view (as the jedi so lovingly say)

Comment: @hedgehog Perhaps you're thinking of Legends? I have no memory of the couple you mention in Canon.

Comment: @RogueJedi If i would remember i would link it :/ but i do remember i read it somewhere...

Answer (score 3):

Their fate is that they were hunted down one by one. We have seen this through Rebels as one former Padawan who left the order before order 66 was executed was still hunted down. Not because she was a rebel but because the empire despite her no longer being a member of the order saw her still as a jedi (indicated through several instaces of Darth Vader speaking about her).

Thus one can subsume that this is the same fate for EVERY former jedi. The Sith still view them as jedi and thus possible threats that need to be converted if useful (inquisitors) or outright destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

I will attempt to answer your question using Legends. In Legends we learn that when Order 66 was enacted, the entire jedi council was wiped out, except for Obi-Wan, Yoda, and Shaak Ti. Shaak Ti took refuge on Felucia and was eventually hunted down and killed by Darth Vader's apprentice, Galen Marek. This was shown in the now non-canon game Force Unleashed. During Order 66, former jedi council member Depa Bilahba is unconcious in the medical wing, and it is implied that she is killed. The fates of Eeth Koth and Coleman Kcaj are not shown, though their lack of future appearances suggests their demise. All other council members were wiped out. It's worth noting that Shaak Ti was training an army of felucians and training an apprentice (Maris Brood) before her death.

Comment: Are any of those actually Jedi who left the order or were expelled from the order before that time? The question is not asking about Jedi who were still part of the Jedi Order when Palpatine initiated Order 66.